# Linear transformation matrix using the standard bases in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Let T : $\mathbb{R^3}$$\to$$\mathbb{R^3}$ be the linear transformation $$T(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (2x_1-x_2,2x_2+3x_3,3x_1+4x_3)^T$$ for all $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R^3}$

I need to calculate $[T]_\varepsilon$ of the operator $T$ corresponding to the standard basis $\varepsilon$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$, where $\varepsilon={\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}}$, $e_1=(1,0,0)^T , e_2=(0,1,0)^T , e_3=(0,0,1)^T$.

I also need to show whether $T$ is one-to-one or not, and explain why.

What I did so far (not sure if I am correct):

$[T(e)]_\varepsilon = A[e]_\varepsilon$
$= Ae_1 + Ae_2 + Ae_3$
$$=\left[{\begin{array}{ccc}2&-1&0\\0&2&3\\3&0&4\\\end{array}}\right]\left[{\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\\\end{array}}\right]+\left[{\begin{array}{ccc}2&-1&0\\0&2&3\\3&0&4\\\end{array}}\right]\left[{\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\0\\\end{array}}\right]+\left[{\begin{array}{ccc}2&-1&0\\0&2&3\\3&0&4\\\end{array}}\right]\left[{\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1\\\end{array}}\right]= A$$

I have just gone in a circle and come back out with A.

Comment: What do you denote $e$?

Comment: Try to see that $T(e_1),T(e_2),T(e_3)$ are linearly independent. Hence $\text {Im} (T) = \Bbb R^3.$ So $\ker (T) = \{(0,0,0) \}.$ Therefore $T$ is invertible.

Comment: What is $e$? Is $e = (1,1,1)$? Also how do you get $A$ back? $Ae_1+Ae_2 +Ae_3$ is a $3 \times 1$ matrix while $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: @Bernard our teacher uses e to denote the vectors within the basis $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 is that for finding out if it is one-to-one?
Also, how is $Ae_1+Ae_2+Ae_3$ a 3x1 matrix?I get three lots of 3x1 matrices but i then put them together and they make the same matrix A with dimensions 3x3.

Comment: Each $Ae_i$ is a $3 \times 1$ matrix. When you are taking their sum you are summing the corresponding components. So you will again end up with a $3 \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: In this case $Ae_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ \end{bmatrix},Ae_2 =\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $Ae_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$ So $$Ae_1+Ae_2+Ae_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2-1+0 \\ 0+2+3 \\ 3+0+4 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 5 \\ 7 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Are you a undergraduate student? If so I am very curious to know what have you learnt so far? You did multivariable calculus but can't recall the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit, you are studying linear transformation but don't know properly how to add or multiply matrices. Ridiculous thing to witness.

Answer (score 1):

What is standard is that the matrix of a linear operator in a finite dimensional vector space, relative to a given basis, has column vectors equal to the coordinates of the images of the basis vectors, expressed in that basis. So it is not surprising that, doing the *concatenation* of the three matrices $Ae_1, Ae_2$ and $Ae_3$ (and not their sum), you obtain $A$ again.

Comment: So does that mean what I have done already is all that needs to be done to answer this question? If not, could you please elaborate?

Comment: As far as I understand the question, yes, except you do not make a sum of three matrices.

Comment: What do I make then? I used the three resultant vectors as the columns of the new matrix for the transformation.. thats how i got A back. Can you please explain what else I am meant to do? I dont understand where to go from obtaining these three vectors.

Comment: You just have to explain (in plain language) that the vectors $Ae1, \dots$ are the column vectors of the matrix of $T$ in the basis $\varepsilon$. It's a standard result.